# Dueling DQN updates model architecture and causes issues

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, keras-rl

I create an initial network model with the following acrchitecture.

```
def create_model(env):

    dropout_prob = 0.8 #aggresive dropout regularization
    num_units = 256 #number of neurons in the hidden units
  
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + env.input_shape))
    model.add(Dense(num_units))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    model.add(Dense(num_units))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_prob))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    model.add(Dense(env.action_size))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

Then I call the DQNAgent that updates the network architecture

```
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=env.action_size, memory=memory,
               nb_steps_warmup=settings['train']['warm_up'], 
               target_model_update=settings['train']['update_rate'], policy=policy, enable_dueling_network=True)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=settings['train']['learning_rate']), metrics=['mse'])
```

Doing this results in an updated network architecture - as expected. The issue now is that when I try to call this fitted new network, the original create model function can't accept the saved model weights because the layer architecture doesn't fit at all.

```
print(model.summary())

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_49 (Flatten)         (None, 106)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_147 (Dense)            (None, 128)               13696     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_145 (Activation)  (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_148 (Dense)            (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_49 (Dropout)         (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_146 (Activation)  (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_149 (Dense)            (None, 3)                 195       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_147 (Activation)  (None, 3)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 22,147
Trainable params: 22,147
Non-trainable params: 0

print(dqn.model.summary())
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_49_input (InputLayer (None, 1, 1, 106)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_49 (Flatten)         (None, 106)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_147 (Dense)            (None, 128)               13696     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_145 (Activation)  (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_148 (Dense)            (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_49 (Dropout)         (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_146 (Activation)  (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_149 (Dense)            (None, 3)                 195       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_150 (Dense)            (None, 4)                 16        
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_3 (Lambda)            (None, 3)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 22,163
Trainable params: 22,163
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

So without training a new dqn, I need to find a way to create a network architecture that is created off the original architecture but applies dqn model changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to save the entire model with

```
dqn.model.save('xyz')
```

and then load the model rather than just the weights with in the new function rather than creating the original model and converting it to duelling form.

```
model = keras.models.load_model('xyz')
```